# Chrome browser certificate is not trusted issue using browsermob-proxy

Tags: selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob-proxy

is there away to make chrome ignore the invalid certificate caused by using browsermob-proxy

i'm using google.com just for example reason, in the real case i need to provide credentials and login and the invalid certificate prevent me from continue.

[please note here that the proxy is working perfectly and after i used all args to ignore the certificate issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4Vl.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4Vl.png

```
    import java.io.File;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy;
    import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
    import net.lightbody.bmp.client.ClientUtil;
    import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har;

    public class Proxytest4 {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    BrowserMobProxy proxy = null;

    @Test
    public void actionLaunchRegistrationPage() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/path/chromedriver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/Users/path/hromedriver_issue.log");

        proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        proxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
        proxy.start(0);

        Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.addArguments("--proxy-server=" + seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy());
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");

        // options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");

        // DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        // cap.acceptInsecureCerts();
        // cap.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        // cap.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

        // cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        // options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

        // options.merge(cap);

        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

        // driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"), cap);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // create a new HAR with the label "yahoo.com"
        proxy.newHar("https://www.google.com/");

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        // get the HAR data
        Har har = proxy.getHar();

        // Writing Har to file

        har.getLog().toString();
        har.writeTo(new File("/Users/path/HAR.txt"));
        // driver.quit();
        // browserStackLocal.stop();
        proxy.stop();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is as below:

1- download the browsermob-proxy certificate from the below link:
https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/browsermob-core/src/main/resources/sslSupport/ca-certificate-rsa.cer

2- Open the Keychain Access utility in OS X.

- Select the System option on the left. Click the lock icon in the
  upper-left corner to enable changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LAGv.png)

- In the lower left, select the Certificates option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccQTO.png)

- Drag the certificate you copied to the desktop into the list of
  certificates. After localhost gets added to the System keychain,
  double-click it to open it again. Expand the Trust section and for
  the first option, pick Always Trust.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqfdo.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think `--disable-web-security` is the option you want.

Comment: thanks, but i tried it didn't i get the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED" when try the login

Comment: Yeah, that's a separate issue.